# Laravel Lumen duplicate results by column numbers

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen to make a simple API. I have the following action in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
  $beds = Bed::all();
  return response()->json($beds);
}
```

This is the json result:

```
[
  {
    "0": 2,
    "1": 2000001,
    "2": 3,
    "3": "2016-02-02 21:43:58",
    "4": "2016-02-02 21:43:58",
    "id": 2,
    "bed_id": 2000001,
    "status_id": 3,
    "created_at": "2016-02-02 21:43:58",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-02 21:43:58"
  },
  {
    "0": 3,
    "1": 2000002,
    "2": 4,
    "3": "2016-02-02 21:43:58",
    "4": "2016-02-02 21:43:58",
    "id": 3,
    "bed_id": 2000002,
    "status_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2016-02-02 21:43:58",
    "updated_at": "2016-02-02 21:43:58"
  }
]
```

I have no idea why the results are duplicates. Does anyone have?

UPDATE:

This problem occurs when I use two database connections. I created a config directory in my project and add the file config/database.php with two connections. When I remove this file, that works fine.

Comment: They don't look like duplicates - one has ID of 2, another has ID of 3. Seems that you have two objects in the table and everything is correct

Comment: @DenisMysenko the problem isn't two results. It is the results each have columns and then a copy on the data as numeric properties.

Comment: ah, this is normal too – it's two alternative array formats. Try return response()->json($beds->toArray());

Comment: @DenisMysenko the problem persists.

Comment: What database are you using? Would you mind to post your table structure here?

Comment: @KrisanAlfaTimur this problem occurs when I use two connections. I created a config directory in my project and add the file config/database.php with two connections. When I remove this file, that works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

When the database.php file is created, you need to add the fetch param, like this:

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
...
]
```

Now, that works fine!